# Calculated Column Yes/No based off 3 Yes/No columns

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, calculated-column-formula, validation, yes-no-field

If column A, B & C all show yes then column D should also be yes
If column A, B or C shows no then column D should be no

Can somebody help me write a formula for this to use in a SharePoint calculated column?

Answer (score 0):

Use this validation formula in list settings --> validation settings:

```
=IF(AND([A], [B], [C]), IF([D], TRUE, FALSE), IF([D], FALSE, TRUE))
```

**Note**:

Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

---

If you don't want to manually enter the value for your `[D]` column from list forms & wan to create calculated column (not shown on list forms & you cannot change its value manually), use below formula:

```
=AND([A], [B], [C])
```

Answer (score 0):

The calculated column D should have the following formula:

```
=AND(A,B,C)
```

[image]

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If A,B,C are all yes/no columns, then `=AND(A,B,C)`. If this does not work for you, better first check the column type of all the three columns.